# How to reference a class' name statically?

Tags: class, syntax, dart

How can one use a class' name in a static field of that class (or anywhere statically for that matter)?

I've tried:

```
class MyClass {
  // assert(myStringWithClassName == 'myclass')
  static final String myStringWithClassName = this.runtimeType.toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

It obviously doesn't work as it tries to reference `this` statically.

Further, any resource to lookup references available for a class in static time?

Comment: This question is strange without a context... what exactly are you trying to do? Have you tried the [mirrors](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/server/reflection-with-mirrors) API?

Comment: Does the context necessarily have to be within your horizons and don't contradict your life rules?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `MyClass.class.getSimpleName()`?

`MyClass.class` will give you the Class object representing the class you statically mention. `getSimpleName` will give you the name of that class.

Comment: Sure but, are you certain that your code works in [tag:dart]? I suspect that what you suggest is [tag:java].

Comment: Ah, you’re totally right! Sorry, I missed the dart tag and assumed the question was about Java from looking at the syntax of the code.